# Visual Studio, VB.NET : looping through form's objects from module

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Visual Studio, VB.NET : when looping through form's objects from a module, I can access the properties (i.e. tag or text) of the checkboxes, but I cannot access the properties for the textboxes.

When writing the code, calling c.tag for the checkbox, I type c. and in the Intellisense (the dropdown list with the options) the options such as tag, text, and the properties of the CheckBox show up. I can type c.Tag and it returns the tag value.

However, in the TextBox section, I type c. and in the Intellisense options, none of the properties of the TextBox appear, but rather functions like `ToString`, `Caret`, `TextEdit` instead the TextBox properties.

If I type `c.tag`, I get an error

> BC30456 Tag is not a member of VisualStyleElement.TextBox

This was working fine, and in one of the Visual Studio starts, it just produced the error.

```
Public Sub writeMano(FileName As String, Frm As FI) ' There are TextBoxes and CheckBoxes in from FI

    Dim str As String
    For Each c As CheckBox In Frm.GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        str = c.Tag ' It retrieves the c.Tag value OK
    Next

    For Each c As TextBox In Frm.GroupBox3.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        str = c.tag ' This line gives error "BC30456 Tag is not a member of VisualStyleElement.TextBox", I cannot recover the c.Tag vaue
    Next

  End Sub
```

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Think your problem here might be VisualStyleElement.TextBox rather than a System.Windows.Forms.Textbox (assuming winforms of course).  Would make sure your imports are correct.

Comment: VS tags are ONLY for issues with the IDE itself, NOT issues with code written in VS but that could be written anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by eliminating the imports:

```
'Imports System.Windows
'Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats
'Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement
'Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Status
```